# Custom Border with scaletransform not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using the template below to render a semi-transparent 'label' to display certain data.  as you can see the the display is elliptical (i'm using Border.CornerRadius for this).   I am now trying to popout and contract the label when based on mouse enter/exist.  this works, but the problem is, when popped out, the text displayed appears in rectanble, not elipse..and furthermore it seems that while the text itself is expanded, the border is not, making causing some of the text to become cut off.  So to summarize...how can i make get the pop out to also show as an elipse and not cut any text off?

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LabelTmplt" >
    <Border Name="myBorder" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="9" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
        <Border.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Opacity=".3" Color="Red"/>
        </Border.Background>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" Padding="5,1,5,1.5" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform />
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <Border.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetName="myBorder">
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" To="1.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <BackEase Amplitude="2" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" To="1.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <BackEase Amplitude="2" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetName="myBorder">
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>                
        </Border.Triggers>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Why don't you use an Ellipse for this?

Comment: ellipse doesn't support direct content..i need a textblock in there to display some text

Comment: Can post where you are using this template. I just used this template applied to a content control and I don't see the issue you are talking about.

Comment: You can use a Grid, draw the Ellipse in the back and the TextBlock at front.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the text actually shrinking and growing with the popup you could put it inside a ViewBox

```
    <Viewbox Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" Padding="5,1,5,1.5"/>
    </Viewbox>
```